# How to implement py:attr for a depricated function

Tags: python, properties, documentation, deprecated, attr

In the documentation of the PyPDF2 package there's an instruction to "Use :py:attr:`is_encrypted` instead", refering to the deprecated function isEncrypted.
I use isEncrypted within the following function:

```
def encryption_test(input_file: str) -> bool:
    with open(input_file, 'rb') as pdf_file:
        pdf_reader = PdfFileReader(pdf_file, strict=False)
        return pdf_reader.isEncrypted  # <-- the call to the deprecated function.
```

My question is what does it mean/what should I do?

The link to the relevant part in the PyPDF2 documentation:  [isEncrypted](https://pypdf2.readthedocs.io/en/latest/modules/PdfReader.html?highlight=isEncrypted#PyPDF2.PdfReader.isEncrypted).

Comment: can you add a link to the doc?

Comment: use `pdf_reader.is_encrypted`

Comment: It just say that you should use `pdf_reader.is_encrypted` instead of `pdf_reader.isEncrypted` because this last one will be removed at some point in a futur version.

Comment: Thanks @Kris. That seems to fix it. In the documentation I saw through PyCharm is_encrypted is referred to as a "py:attr", which sounds like an attribute rather than a function.

Answer (score 0):

As commented by @Kris and @ymmx, it simply means using `pdf_reader.is_encrypted` instead of `pdf_reader.isEncrypted`.